# Use dataframe columns as arguments for function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arguments

I want to get arguments from a datafile (excel, .csv, whatever) and pass them as arguments to a Python function.

To get the arguments from the datafile I've converted it to a Pandas dataframe. Created a list of the index of the df and iterate over this list whilst finding all the cell values and passing these as arguments.

I've got some working code (see below) but I feel like it's kinda clunky.
Is there a better way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

curdir = os.getcwd()

def pdFunc(Name, Module): #function that takes multiple arguments from the dataframe
    print(str(Name) + ',' + str(Module))
    #further code will be added here which will create new .csv files etc. This output is not suitable to be placed in a dataframe. 

assetList = os.path.join(curdir, 'Lists', 'Assets_ShortTesting_v1.0.xlsx') # setting path for the excel file with the data
assetdf = pd.read_excel(assetList) #importing the data to a dataframe

indexList = assetdf.index.tolist() #creating list to iterate over

for i in indexList: #iterating over list
    pdFunc(assetdf.loc[i]['Name'], assetdf.loc[i]['Module']) #finding the cell values from the dataframe and setting them as arguments for the function
```

Here's the dataframe:

```
                          Name  ISIN  SymbolYF  SymbolInvestpy Currency        Country   Exchange      Type   Module  Constituent of
0                   Adyen N.V.   NaN  ADYEN.AS             NaN      EUR     Netherlands       NaN      Stock       1             AEX
1                   Aegon N.V.   NaN    AGN.AS             NaN      EUR     Netherlands       NaN      Stock       1             AEX
2                Aalberts N.V.   NaN   AALB.AS             NaN      EUR     Netherlands       NaN      Stock       1             AMX
3           ABN AMRO Bank N.V.   NaN    ABN.AS             NaN      EUR     Netherlands       NaN      Stock       1             AMX
4   Anheuser-Busch InBev SA/NV   NaN    ABI.BR             NaN      EUR         Belgium       NaN      Stock       2           BEL20
5    Ackermans & Van Haaren NV   NaN   ACKB.BR             NaN      EUR         Belgium       NaN      Stock       2           BEL20
6           L'Air Liquide S.A.   NaN     AI.PA             NaN      EUR          France       NaN      Stock       2           CAC40
7                    Airbus SE   NaN    AIR.PA             NaN      EUR          France       NaN      Stock       2           CAC40
8                   Vonovia SE   NaN    VNA.DE             NaN      EUR         Germany       NaN      Stock       2             DAX
9                    US Dollar   NaN   USD-EUR             NaN      EUR              US       NaN      Forex       3           Forex
10                   Shiba Inu   NaN  SHIB-EUR             NaN      EUR             NaN       NaN     Crypto       3           Forex
11                   FTSE 1000   NaN     ^FTSE             NaN      EUR  United Kingdom       NaN      Index       3           Index
12                       Wheat   NaN      ZW=F             NaN      USD             NaN       NaN  Commodity       3       Commodity
13                  Apple Inc.   NaN      AAPL             NaN      USD              US       NaN      Stock       4      US MegaCap
14     Sirius XM Holdings Inc.   NaN      SIRI             NaN      USD              US       NaN      Stock       4  US High volume
```

Comment: You could do `assetdf[["Name", "Module"]].apply(lambda row: pdFunc(*row), axis=1)`

Comment: Sidenote: Don't do something like `assetdf.loc[i]['Name']`. Use `assetdf.at[i, 'Name']` instead. `assetdf.loc[i, 'Name']` works too, and is better than your version, but `.at` is specifically designed for single cell access (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-basics-get-value)).